# Apply Microsoft-provided site template to a site with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, site-template

Microsoft published an update MC294082, which says "Now you have the choice to use SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets to decide which Microsoft-provided site templates will be displayed or hidden when viewing the site template gallery" with `Set-SPOBuiltInSiteTemplateSettings`.

Is there a way to apply any of Microsoft-provided site templates (Built In Site Templates) to a site with PowerShell?
`Invoke-SPOSiteDesign` with Built-In Site Template Id fails with `Invoke-SPOSiteDesign : File Not Found.` error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Invoke-SPOSiteDesign` to apply site design on existing site. Please make sure the ID you used is correct.

PowerShell commands:

```
#Set Parameters
$AdminCenterURL = "https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$SiteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx"
$SiteDesignId = "xxxxxx"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
 
#Apply Site Design
Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity $SiteDesignId -WebUrl $SiteURL
```

For Reference: [SharePoint Online: Create Site Design and Site Scripts using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/10/sharepoint-online-site-design-and-site-scripts.html)

Comment: Hi Casey. There is no problem invoking custom site design. 
My question was a little different: how to invoke a built-in (Microsoft-provided) site design

Answer (score 0):

the existing PnP PowerShell and SPO Management shell don't allow you to apply OOTB Site Design template to a site collection. If you want to apply OOTB site design template to a site collection, you can use REST API with following syntax:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Method | POST |
| Url | https://{{r_siteUrl}}/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.WebTemplateExtensions.SiteScriptUtility.ApplySiteDesign |
| Body | { "siteDesignId": "{{r_sitedesignId}}", "webUrl": "{{r_targetSiteUrl}}", "store":1 } |
| Description | r_siteUrl: the site collection you want to run REST API r_sitedesignid: this is OOTB site design template id which can get from [Set-SPOBuiltInSiteTemplateSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spobuiltinsitetemplatesettings?view=sharepoint-ps) r_targetSiteUrl: the site collection Url you want to apply to. r_siteUrl and r_targetSiteUrl can be a same site collection |